# C++ Bubble Array Assignment - Adding markers to show change

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort

I was given an assignment to work through in university and one part of that assignment was to add stars(`*`) to elements moved in an array using bubble sort. I've tried a few different things to try to get this to work but nothing ends up working. Here is what's specifically asked of me:

> "5. Create an extra array of bools (one for each element in the array), so that if a pair of
>   elements are changed round in a cycle, the bools change to true, and those elements
>   are displayed surrounded by stars (`*`) to show that the change has occurred. Then
>   reset the array of bools to false, ready for the next cycle. REMEMBER you need to
>   TEST the value of the Boolean in order to decide whether to output the asterisks or not"

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    double Numbers[NMAX] = {31.2, 29.7, 53.5, 69.0, 23.7, 71.8, 49.3, 52.9, 51.3, 57.1};
    bool change[NMAX] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    // note this top counter, i, counts down
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i=NMAX-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        //and this counter, j, only goes as far as the current i value 
        // it means it doesn't go over the elements that have already 'bubbled up' to the end of the array
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            double temp;
            // Compare 2 values - increment a counter here
            counter++;

            if (Numbers[j]>Numbers[j+1])
            {
                temp = Numbers[j];
                Numbers[j]= Numbers[j+1];
                Numbers[j+1]= temp;
                cout << "Array: " << endl;
                change[j] = true;
                change[j + 1] = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    cout << Numbers[i] << ", ";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // display the sorted array:
    cout << endl;
    cout<<"ARRAY CONTENTS SORTED, IMPLEMENTATION 1 "<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<NMAX; i++)
    {
        cout<<Numbers[i]<<endl;
    }
    //Display the values of the counter after the whole sort
    return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, so apologies if my question is irritatingly formatted.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community! Articles describing what makes a good question can be found in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). As for this question you are doing fine, but it would help to be more specific about what doesn't work - better diagnostics lead to better answers.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    cout << Numbers[i] << ", ";
                }

This for loop iterates the array and the changes made to it through each stage of the bubble sort. I've made a second array called change which stores variables in bool form which my teacher wants me to somehow use to have stars displayed beside the elements changed in each iteration. This is specifically where I'm confused.

Comment: During that loop the number `i` is used to display the value of `Number[i]`. What can you do with `change[i]` now that it the value `true` at the indices of the values that have changed places? Hint: think "if statements".

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
     if (change[i] = true)
     {
      cout << Numbers[i] << "*, ";
     }
     else
     {
      cout << Numbers[i] << ", ";
     }

     change[i] = false;

This is what I've made for the second last for loop. All the booleans are changed to true and *'s are added to everything. I'm banging my head against the wall, trying to figure out how to reset them before each iteration :P

Comment: Need the `==` operator instead of `=`, but that's almost it! As for resetting the changes array, just iterate over it setting everything to false once you've finished any printing - no need to be overly elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why that extra array of `bool`s was required if
you still remember the `j` and `j+1` were exchanged when you output `Numbers`. I would write simply:

```
for (int n = 0; n < NMAX; ++n)
{
    if (n == j + 1 || n == j) 
        cout << '*' << Numbers[n] << "*, ";
    else
        cout << Numbers[n] << ", ";
}
```

However if there was such a requirement then follow it and try to achieve same effect by checking contents of that `bool` array of yours. Also remember to reset it back to `false` like required.

Comment: I'm not sure why either. It is just a requirement of the task. I'm having trouble resetting it back to false.for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
     if (change[i] = true)
     {
      cout << Numbers[i] << "*, ";
     }
     else
     {
      cout << Numbers[i] << ", ";
     }

     change[i] = false;

As you can see, I try to set it back to false here with no avail.

Comment: @Dprog, in C++ we compare for equality with == not =, latter is assignment even inside if. Also it is more common to check bool array element using if(change[i]) not if(change[i]==true) but that is just matter of taste perhaps

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thank you very much. It won't let me give you a vote because I'm new.

Comment: You can likely accept the answer unless someone gives better one.